# JSON file reading an array in Java AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to read data from JSON file in AndroidStudio with a format as follows:

```
{
"records": [
    [1,"name1","1,9"],
    [2,"name2","0,74"],
    ...
]}
```

I want to have objects containing int, String, String (new Object for each row). Does someone know how to write that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserializing JSON string in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38135957/deserializing-json-string-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This may help**

```
JSONObject jsonObject ;// your json body 
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("records");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray jArray = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);// for each row in records([2,"name2","0,74"])
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```